# When compiling C in VScode, launch: program '' does not exist

Tags: c, gcc, vscode-tasks

I am a beginner in C.

When I pressed F5(which execute (Windows) Launch) to run the code, I have got this error.
[image: error message]

Here are what my explorer looks like and my launch.json and tasks.json.

```
├─.vscode
│  ├─launch.json
│  ├─tasks.json
├─hello.c
├─hello.exe
```

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g", 
                "${file}", 
                "-o", 
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-fexec-charset=GBK"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "new", 
        "showReuseMessage": true,
        "clear": false
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "cmd",
            "preLaunchTask": "echo",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "args": [
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "&",
                "echo.",
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole":true,        
        },
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole":true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",// 自己电脑的gdb
            "preLaunchTask": "echo",//这里和task.json的label相对应
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
            
        }
    ]
}
```

I was confused, I have no idea why no content in quotation marks "" because the .exe file does exist and I assumed the path is correct, I have also tried to compile and run the code by cmd.

```
C:\Users\***>gcc -g d:\workspace\hi.c -o hi.exe -fexec-charset=GBK

C:\Users\***>D:

D:\>cd workspace

D:\workspace>hi.exe & echo.
hello,world!
```

It works fine,

does anyone know what is going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer directly to your question about your `(Windows) Launch)` launch target, you need to add the `/C` to pass arguments to `cmd.exe`. Your arg value should look like this:

```json
"args": [
    "/C",
    "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "&",
    "echo.",
    "&",
    "pause",
],
```

Notes:

- I added the pause to keep the external window open.
- `externalConsole` is deprecated. It can be replaced with             `"console": "newExternalWindow"`

Comment: thanks! I thought `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"` already declares the working directory so i don't have to pass arguments like "/C"